# How to use browserify and Gulp?

Tags: javascript, gulp, browserify

I have got the following browserify command which I run from the interactive terminal of Visual Studio Code.

```
browserify -r ./../app/aws/googleAuth.js:googleAuth  -r    
          ./../app/aws/awsServices.js:awsServices  -r 
         ./../app/bower_components/bluebird/js/browser/bluebird.min.js:Promise 
          -r ./node_modules/aws4/aws4.js:aws4 -g aliasify -r ./../app
          /aws/config.js:config > ./../app/bundle.js
```

I would like to use gulp to run this and also minify it but I am not sure how to pass in all the flags into the bundle() command of browserify.